# why does "a->content" give me a address instead of a value?

Tags: c++, pointers

now i have been making games for a few years using the gm:s engine(tho i assure you i aint some newbie who uses drag and drop, as is all to often the case), and i have decided to start to learn to use c++ on its own, you know expand my knowledge and all that good stuff =D

while doing this, i have been attempting to make a list class as a practice project, you know, have a set of nodes linked together, then loop threw those nodes to get a value at a index, well here is my code, and i ask as the code has a single major issue that i struggle to understand

```
template<class type>
class ListNode
{
    public:
        type content;
        ListNode<type>* next;
        ListNode<type>* prev;
        ListNode(type content) : content(content), next(NULL), prev(NULL) {}
    protected:
    private:
};
template<class type>
class List
{
    public:
        List() : SIZE(0), start(NULL), last(NULL) {}
        unsigned int Add(type value)
        {
            if (this->SIZE == 0)
            {
                ListNode<type> a(value);
                this->start = &a;
                this->last = &a;
            }
            else
            {
                ListNode<type> a(value);
                this->last->next = &a;
                a.prev = this->last;
                this->last = &a;
            }
            this->SIZE++;
            return (this->SIZE - 1);
        }
        type Find(unsigned int pos)
        {
            ListNode<type>* a = this->start;
            for(unsigned int i = 0; i<this->SIZE; i++)
            {
                if (i < pos)
                {
                    a = a->next;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    return (*a).content;
                }
                continue;
            }
        }
    protected:
    private:
        unsigned int SIZE;
        ListNode<type>* start;
        ListNode<type>* last;
};
```

regardless, to me at least, this code looks fine, and it works in that i am able to create a new list without crashing, as well as being able to add elements to this list with it returning the proper index of those elements from within the list, however, beyond that the problem arises when getting the value of a element from the list itself, as when i ran the following test code, it didn't give me what it was built to give me

```
List<int> a;
unsigned int b = a.Add(313);
unsigned int c = a.Add(433);
print<unsigned int>(b);
print<int>(a.Find(b));
print<unsigned int>(c);
print<int>(a.Find(c));
```

now this code i expected to give me

```
0
313
1
433
```

as that's what is been told to do, however, it only half does this, giving me

```
0
2686684
1
2686584
```

now, this i am at a lost, i assume that the values provided are some kind of pointer address, but i simply don't understand what those are meant to be for, or what is causing the value to become that, or why

hence i ask the internet, wtf is causing these values to be given, as i am quite confused at this point

my apologies if that was a tad long and rambling, i tend to write such things often =D

thanks =D

Comment: The assumption that these are "pointer addresses" is wrong. Don't make assumptions.

Comment: Also, would it kill you to use capital letters and full stops?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have lots of [*undefined behaviors*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code, when you store pointers to local variables and later dereference those pointers. Local variables are destructed once the scope they were declared in ends.

Example:

```
if (this->SIZE == 0)
{
    ListNode<type> a(value);
    this->start = &a;
    this->last = &a;
}
```

Once the closing brace is reached the scope of the `if` body ends, and the variable `a` is destructed. The pointer to this variable is now a so called *stray pointer* and using it in any way will lead to undefined behavior.

The solution is to allocate the objects dynamically using `new`:

```
auto* a = new ListNode<type>(value);
```

Or if you don't have a C++11 capable compiler

```
ListNode<type>* a = new ListNode<type>(value);
```

Comment: thanks lad, but what must one do in order to not loose context on the pointer?

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion: use valgrind or a similar memory checker to execute this program.  You will probably find there are many memory errors caused by dereferencing stack pointers that are out of scope.

Second suggestion: learn about the difference between objects on the stack and objects on the heap.  (Hint: you want to use heap objects here.)

Third suggestion: learn about the concept of "ownership" of pointers.  Usually you want to be very clear which pointer variable should be used to delete an object.  The best way to do this is to use the `std::unique_ptr` smart pointer.  For example, you could decide that each ListNode is owned by its predecessor:

```
    std::unique_ptr<ListNode<type>> next;
    ListNode<type>* prev;
```

and that the List container owns the head node of the list

```
    std::unique_ptr<ListNode<type>> start;
    ListNode<type>* last;
```

This way the compiler will do a lot of your work for you at compile-time, and you wont have to depend so much on using valgrind at runtime.